# Prove the following function is convex

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

we have function $\Phi(x)=\int_{0}^{|x|} \phi(x) \,dx$ where $\phi(x)$ is an increasing function and $x\in R$
My try is we have to show that $\Phi(\alpha x+\beta y)\leq \alpha\Phi(x)+\beta \Phi(y)$ where $\alpha+\beta=1$, $0\leq \alpha,\beta \leq 1$ so we have now
$\Phi(\alpha x+\beta y)=\int_{0}^{|\alpha x+\beta y|} \phi(x) \,dx$ from this step I have no idea how do I proceed .Please if anyone give some hint or solution.

Comment: Consider cases:  Show that for $x>0$, function is concave up, likewise for $x<0$.  Finally, show that second derivative is positive at zero.

Comment: are you allowed to use second derivative test, or are you supposed to prove directly from definition?

Comment: I want to prove it by definition.

Comment: Because $x$ plays two different roles here, it would be clearer to use a different dummy variable of integration: $\Phi(x)=\int_0^{|x|} \phi(t) \mathrm{d}t$.